# Liferay portlet on python

Tags: python, liferay-6, portlet

I have a problem with a writing portlet for Liferay on python because I can't find any information about libraries that use there. Also there are now information about this on official site. 
But there guy developed something similar [Getting journal articles by category: Liferay Portlet written in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20478938/getting-journal-articles-by-category-liferay-portlet-written-in-python) 
Does anybody know how to write portlet on python? How to run it and deploy?

Answer (score 0):

As the portlet specification is a Java Standard, I'm guessing that you'll find very few people who are using it on other languages (like Python or PHP). You might be able to make it work, but the future maintenance might suffer (with Liferay 7 moving on to OSGi and Liferay 6.x not getting any more updates already)

If you must integrate a Python webapp, I'd think about iframe (with Single Sign On) or Liferay's Webproxy portlet. Or write services in Python and consume them from a thin portlet deployed to Liferay (potentially including SSO again). Or just bite the bullet and go with Java. You'll get the most support in the Java realm, as most people use that language to develop on Liferay.